# i am trying to call node api (which scan aws) from java spring boot but getting Unexpected end of file from server;

Tags: java, node.js

java code

```java
final String uri = "http://localhost:3000/scan"; 
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, awsCredentials, String.class);
```

you can check below url for node js project (index.js,engine method)

https://github.com/cloudsploit/scans

```
    {
    "timestamp": "2020-01-16T12:58:00.026+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "I/O error on POST request for \"http://localhost:3000/scan\": Unexpected end of file from server; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server",
    "trace": "org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for \"http://localhost:3000/scan\": Unexpected end of file from server; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:751)\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:677)\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:452)\n\tat com.cloudscan.controller.ReadCsvController.scan(ReadCsvController.java:26)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\nCaused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:862)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1610)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1515)\n\tat java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)\n\tat org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:55)\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:61)\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:773)\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:743)\n\t... 53 more\n",
    "path": "/scan"
}
```

Comment: can you show the error msg with stack trace ?

Comment: i have edited the question with errors please have a look

Comment: @user7755390 - could you please format your code better, it's pretty difficult to read. Also the stack trace is in a long sausage, please format it. If possible show more of your code